# Event on HTML selection

Tags: html, browser, google-chrome

Is there an event for situations where something is selected on an HTML page like arbitrary text within a `span` element?  Does such a thing exist or does one need to poll at regular interval & analyze the `window.getSelection()` ?

I would like to trap this event type from within a browser extension (Chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New York Times implements some "on selection" type of functionality on all their articles without monitoring for a specific "onselection" event.  [Example here](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/05/19/world/19sanctions.html), highlight some text and you'll see a "?" pop up that you can use for search.

[Here's the relevant code](http://graphics8.nytimes.com/js/common/screen/altClickToSearch.js).  Basically looks like onmouseup of any body text, they get the document (or window) selection and use that.

The existing "onselect" event is [spec'd to only apply to input and textarea elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3).

Comment: "OnMouseUp" event on the `body` ... why look for a complex solution when there's a simple one!  Thanks!!

Comment: Well, the simple one's not quite watertight. You can make a selection without using the mouse (eg. keyboard shift+arrows in some browsers), which this approach won't catch.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can use the `select()` function to bind an event handler to the `select` event. For more info, see http://api.jquery.com/select/

Comment: hmmm... seems like one has to modify the page in order to "inject" handlers... that's not what I am asking for here.